# Clr Assembly must have main file specified error

Tags: dll, clr, ssas, cube, security-roles

This is the first dll I have made. It's purpose is to grab territory names from a database and return as an mdx set. The dll compiled perfectly fine, but when I go to deploy the dll as an assembly in bids to my cube, I get the following error:

Clr Assembly must have main file specified error

The dll is supposed to be like a ssas stored procedure so I can set permission in a role for ssas.

Thanks!
Ethan

Comment: Also, my dll references msmgdsv.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution! I believe that because of the msmgdsv.dll being of framework 2.0 I didn't like the file, so I changed the target framework under the project properties to Framework 2.0 from Framework 4.0. I then went to deploy everything from BIDS and instead of an error, It deployed!